# Hide keyboard plus return key?

Tags: swift, xcode6, uitextview, ios8.2

I have a view with a textfield at the top, a textview under it and two buttons below the textview.

The keyboard is configured with a "Done" button.  Once the user has typed in their info, they click the save button, which is below the textview.  First they click Done to hide the keyboard (and reveal the save button) then click the save button.

I need to allow carriage returns in the textview but "Return" is already taken up by Done.

How is it usually handled when you need a Return key and ability to also hide the keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a UINavigationBar or have other buttons or fields, activating any of those UIControls could be detected and used to dismiss the keyboard via resignFirstResponder().  In fact Save/Cancel/Done are UIBarButtonItems and are a standard mechanism for completing things and changing state, and create a framework for accomplishing what you want. If you don't take that approach then you have to get creative with how you do it, and also make it clear to the user what needs to be done.

In Interface Builder you can change the type of your main view from UIView to UIControl and then use addTarget() to detect touch events as a 'touch outside' area and use those actions to resign first responder as well.  But you might want to consider a UINavigationBar or some other button bar or tab interface to make state transitions.

Also review [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/) document. It's a great document for understanding how iOS is designed to handle common situations like what you are dealing with, and it can get you out of design ruts. It's well written and worth re-visiting periodically.

Answer (score 2):

Drag a button into your view, delete the text, and resize it to take up the entire view. In the document outline, select the new button and drag it to the top of the list of elements. This puts it in the background so it is not hiding the elements of your view.

Add this code to your ViewController:

```
@IBAction func hideKeyboard(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.textField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Link the button to this action and you're all set.

Comment: Easier just to make the UIView (superview) a UIControl as described in the previous answer

Comment: While @1sand0s helped explain how to resolve the overall issue, Shades answer definitely helps in how to hide the keyboard once the navbar button is clicked. Both good answers.